# How to implement mui Timepicker with latest 6 version with formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, material-ui, formik

I am working with MUI react [Timepicker](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/time-picker/).
And I want to integrate it using Formik with validation but the issue is the values are not getting bound in the initialValues of the form.

```
const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState({
  mondayFrom: "",
  mondayTo: "",
});
const onSubmit = async (values: RegisterFormProps) => {
  console.log({values})//here not getting mondayFrom: ""
}

    <Formik initialValues={initialValues} enableReinitialize onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  {({
    values,
    errors,
    touched,
    handleSubmit,
    handleChange,
    isSubmitting,
    setFieldValue,
  }) => (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field name="mondayFrom">
        {(field) => (
          <TimePicker
            {...field}
            ampm={false}
            format="HH:mm"
            slotProps={{
              textField: {
                label: "Monday From",
                size: "small",
                fullWidth: true,
              },
            }}
          />
        )}
      </Field>
    </Form>
  )}
</Formik>;
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you just want to use a MUI component in Formik. If that's the case, there is a library that can serve your need. Are you alright with using external libraries?

Comment: @deepanshu I guess you are talking about the library formik-material-ui. But why the timepicker does not work with the Field as the other component does

Comment: I think its probably because, the argument to `onChange` handler  is a "time value", and not a “synthetic event” unlike other components. Therefore, if you need to make it work, you need to pass a custom `onChange` handler. Does this helps?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost correct, but there are two issues.

1. Destructuring field.
2. There's an [open issue bug](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/3493) which states

> the DateTime picker doesn't set the same type of data as in the
> initialValues. DateTime picker sends an object containing a property
> which is the date time in full string format.

`onChange` is added to overcome that bug by overriding `field`'s `onChange` property.
This code, very similar to your code just apply those fixes.

```
function App() {
    const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState({
        mondayFrom: "", mondayTo: "",
    });
    const onSubmit = async (values: RegisterFormProps) => {
        console.log({values})//here not getting mondayFrom: ""
        console.log(initialValues)
    }

    return (<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale="en">
            <div style={{margin: 20, padding: 20}}>
                <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                    {({
                          handleSubmit,values, errors, touched, handleChange, isSubmitting, setFieldValue,
                      }) => (<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Field name="mondayFrom">
                            {({field}) => {
                               return (<TimePicker
                                ampm={false}
                                format="HH:mm"
                                slotProps={{
                                    textField: {
                                        label: "Monday From", size: "small", fullWidth: true,
                                    },
                                }}
                                   {...field}
                                onChange={(value)=> {
                                    setInitialValues({mondayTo: initialValues.mondayTo,mondayFrom: value.toString()})
                                }}
                            />)}
                            }
                        </Field>
                    </Form>)}
                </Formik>
            </div>
        </LocalizationProvider>);
}
```

**Update:**
As pointed out by [Profer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6838854/profer) in comments, a better way for `onChange` is

```
onChange={(value) => setFieldValue('mondayFrom', value.format("hh:mm"))}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the best way is to use just format `onChange={(value) => setFieldValue('mondayFrom', value.format("hh:mm"))}`

Answer (score 0):

You should also include `onChange` to the `TimePicker`, so every time you change it, you set the new value to form values:

```html
<Formik
 initialValues={initialValues}
 enableReinitialize
 onSubmit={onSubmit} >
   {({ handleSubmit }) => (
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
         <Field name="mondayFrom">
            {({ field, form }) => (
               <TimePicker
                  {...field}
                  ampm={false}
                  format="HH:mm"
                  slotProps={{
                    textField: {
                      label: "Monday From",
                      size: "small",
                      fullWidth: true
                    }
                  }}
                  onChange={(value) => {
                    form.setFieldValue(field.name, value);
                  }}
                />
              )}
         </Field>
      </Form>
   )}
</Formik>
```

Here´s a code sample [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-witk-timepicker-k6lx3t?file=/demo.tsx).

* i'm using `dayjs` as `dateadapter` in the example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the best way is to use just format `onChange={(value) => setFieldValue('mondayFrom', value.format("hh:mm"))}`

Answer (score 0):

### Gist

The problem here is, that the component that you are using (`TimePicker`), behaves a bit differently than other components.

### Formik and onChange handler

Formik, as you may know, makes it easier to develop forms in react. It does this, maintaing internal state of all input components, and by calling `onChange` handler whenever user enters input in the `input` component.

So normally, when there is a input change, `onChange` handles gets called with "synthetic event" as an argument.

```
onChange = (e) => setInput(e.target.value)
```

### TimePicker and onChange handler

But, in the case of `TimePicker` component in MUI, whenever the `onChange` handler is called, arguments that is provided to the handler, is not "synthetic event", but the component's data value.

```
Object { "$L": "en", "$u": undefined, "$d": Date Tue Jun 20 2023 10:10:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), "$x": {}, "$y": 2023, "$M": 5, "$D": 20, "$W": 2, "$H": 0, "$m": 10, … }
```

As you can see, there is no `event.target.value`, the value is just `event`.

So, when Formik tries to access `event.target.value`, it is not able to. And therefore, the value is not reflected in the component.

### The Solution

In order to circumvent this problem, you need to create your own custom `onChange` event handler. And you can do this by using, [setFieldValue](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1243#issuecomment-461176174) which is present in Formik.

And this will essentially set the `mondayFrom` field value automatically for you.

```
       <TimePicker
                {...field}
                ampm={false}
                format="HH:mm"
                onChange={(e) => form.setFieldValue(field.name, e)}
                slotProps={{
                  textField: {
                    label: "Monday From",
                    size: "small",
                    fullWidth: true,
                  },
                }}
              />
```

The data object `e` above, also has a property "$d" using which you could get the date time value in string format:

```
   console.log(e["$d"])
   // Date Tue Jun 20 2023 10:10:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the best way is to use just format `onChange={(value) => setFieldValue('mondayFrom', value.format("hh:mm"))}`

Comment: @Profer that depends on your use case. The question was about why it was not working, so i've answered that.

Comment: @Profer Have I not answered your question?